# Below is a list of dictionary which I am trying to add in Excel

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

```
    test = [
    {
    'product': 'Business 1',
    'amount': '1000000',
    'old_date': '01 Mar,2018 19:18:29',
    'num': '2',
    'status': 'review'
  },
  {
    'product': 'Business 2',
    'amount': '1000000',
    'new_date': '01 Mar,2018 19:18:29',
    'num': '92',
    'status': 'progress'
  }
]
```

How do I automate the process as the new_date and old_date keys keep changing based on data. It is basically a python list of dictionaries where out of 5 keys one key keeps changing. How do I dynamically add this to excel or CSV?

Comment: Are trying to append this to an existing excel file or csv? Or create a new excel or csv file each time?

Comment: Create a new XLS/CSV each time.